# multiple copies of same column into new dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Using `pandas-python`:

I have an existing dataframe that is lets say
 `Dataframe A (18 rows, 40 columns)`.

I created a new dataframe that we can name `Dataframe B (18 rows, 127 columns)` (this doesn't entirely matter).

I want to loop through each column of `Dataframe A` (or not loop), and copy each column to `Dataframe B`... EXCEPT, I want to copy that column 3 times on every column of `A` except every 4th column starting from 0.

> Example:
>   If `col_headers` of `A` for the first 5 were `[0,1,2,3,4]`, I would want
>   the associated `col_headers` with same values to be on `B` as:
>   `[0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4]`

I am trying to see if there is a quick way to loop or not loop, using potentailly built in functions to do a process such as this. I have already come up with a way to do it looping, but I'm trying to avoid a heavy computation if possible.

Answer (score 3):

First create a list of column identifiers in the order you require. Then use [`pd.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html). Note that `iloc`, like NumPy, accepts repeated integers for indexing by postion.

Here's a demo:

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]],
                  columns=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

L = list(chain.from_iterable([[j]*3 if i%4 else [j] \
         for i, j in enumerate(df.columns)]))

res = df.iloc[:, L]

print(res)

   0  1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3   4
0  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  4  4   5
1  6  7  7  7  8  8  8  9  9  9  10
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,size=(18,40)))
df1_cols=df1.columns.values
req_cols= sum([[col]*3 if col%4!=0 else [col] for col in df1_cols],[])
res=pd.concat(df2,df1[req_cols])


# req_cols:

[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 28, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 32, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 36, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39]
```

Explanation:

You need to first take a columns into list. then repeat column into 3 times when %4!=0 for your problem. so `req_cols` contains a columns which you required. then slice this from df1. Finally to copy contents merge with df2. you will get a desired result successfully.

Comment: @jpp - DataFrame A (df1), DataFrame B (df2). concat performed because of this sentence `I want to loop through each column of Dataframe A (or not loop), and copy each column to Dataframe B`